# Psycopg2 Use Table and Column Name as Parameters in a Function

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am developing a program that uses a Postgresql database and am trying to create a function that will let me pass two arguments, the table and column that I want.  The function will then retrieve that column from the given table and display as a dataframe.  When I run my code I receive the following error message:

relation "RAW_MTL" does not exist
LINE 1: select "Ball_LT_NUM" from "RAW_MTL"

My code is as follows:
'''

```
def get_lot_numbers(table, table_lot):

     con = db_connect()

     try:
         with con:
             with con.cursor() as cur:

                 db_query = sql.SQL("select {field} from {table}").format(
                     field=sql.Identifier(table_lot),
                     table=sql.Identifier(table))

                 cur.execute(db_query)

                 results = cur.fetchall()

                 df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Lot Number'])

         return df

     except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
         print(error, datetime.now())
     finally:
         if con is not None:
             con.close()


df_lot_numbers = get_lot_numbers(table_lot='Ball_LT_NUM', table='RAW_MTL')
print(df_lot_numbers)
```

'''

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the table name in the database actually `RAW_MTL`, in other words all upper case? If so is a [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) issue?

Comment: So it turns out I had two mistakes.  First was the search path issue you identified and then second was 'Ball_LT_NUM' which should have been 'BALL_LT_NUM' which you kind of identified too!  Thanks for the help.  Can I mark a comment as correct?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit should go to Adrian who commented on my question.  Issue was related to the search path due to multiple schemas being in the database.  Link below.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH